# Rails 3 devise auth as main page without layout rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, root

I've a question, I need to put standart devise authorization page as root page, like this:

```
root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
```

But I've this error:

```
Unknown action
AbstractController::ActionNotFound
```

Can somebody help me? And how I can render this page without main site layout.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The root of your project should be a landing page and not the login screen. Login screen should be shown when user is not authenticated.

Put `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in your controllers that you wish to have user authentication required and devise will `show session/new` automatically.

Comment: Yes, of course, I want to make devise auth page for new unregistered users.

Comment: Ok, thanks, btw how I can disable main layout in the devise auth page?

Comment: Devise comes with a predefined "log in" page and "sign up" page, `sessions/new` and `registrations/new` respectively. You can link to registration page like this: `<%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> and to log in page as this: `<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>`. There's a great tutorial that helped me greatly: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise Hope it helps.

Comment: For layouts: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts Although I have not tried it personally.

Comment: If you think the answer is right, please consider "accepting" it as an answer. This greatly helps StackOverflow community.